# Phonegap open local powerpoint file

Tags: cordova, window.open, inappbrowser

Is it possibile to open a local power point file with window.open option? Because i have tried but nothing happens!

This is the code

```
 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///sdcard/brickExample.ppt", function(dirEntry) {
                alert(dirEntry.name);
                var b = window.open(dirEntry.toURL(), '_system', 'location=no');
                alert(b);
        }, function(error){ alert(error)});
```

Comment: check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19449495/phonegap-open-file-in-native-app-build-via-build-phonegap-com

Comment: I can't use external plugin because i use intel xdk. I have tried with pdf and it works, but with .ppt nothing happens. I have two apps that open ppt files installed on phone, but nothing...

Comment: okay, you can also try by taking absolute path of file as mentioned [here](http://bighow.net/3884895-Open_ppt_file_in_External_SdCard.html) .

Comment: The problem isn't absolute path. Same function with pdf file open the Android "Open With" option and works. But with ppt file nothing. I have two apps with i can open ppt file